# Time and calendar in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For time my code is-

```
import time;  

ticks = time.time()
print "Output is :", ticks
```

And for calendar my code is-

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.month(2014, 1)
print "Here is the calendar:"
print cal;
```

But show *invalid syntax*. Why?

Comment: in python 3.x , print is a function. In 2.x it's an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print` function is wrong. You are following the Python2 syntax. In Python3, `print` is made a function, unlike in Python2.

It should be

```
print("Output is :", ticks)
print(cal)
print("Here is the calendar:")
```

Instead.

Apart from that, everything else is fine. Infact if you run this in Py2 you will get the output.

```
Output is : 1423394876.34    
Here is the calendar:
    January 2014
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: @Neo You have to delimit by semicolon `;` and not `,` That is `import calendar; cal = calendar.month(2014, 1); print(cal);`

Comment: Thank you @Bhargav Rao. I am new in python. So I am facing lots of problems in simple part.

Comment: remove that trailing semicolon!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank god the Python devs considered `;`